# PHP and SQLite Service in Memory

Tags: php, performance, sqlite, form-submit

I have a single page responsive HTML page.  One section of the page has a product search.  User can enter search criteria in a form and get back the results. The results are paged.

```
<form id="filterform" name="filterform" method="post" action="./loaddata.php">
   ...
</form>
```

The form is submitted by Ajax and the results are returned as an HTML fragment that gets dynamically inserted into the DOM to refresh the results.

That's all working OK, but sometimes the results from loaddata.php are very slow, usually the first time called from the page.

In loaddata.php I'm using a Sqlite3 database.  It is read only.  Something like the following:

```
$filename = "../datafile.sqlite3";
$db = new SQLite3($filename);
$q = "SELECT distinct productId, title, price, name FROM datatable LIMIT 16";
$results = $db->query($q);
while ($row = $results->fetchArray()) {
    echo "<h1>Results</h1>";
}
$db->close();
```

Is there a way to make loaddata.php load and stay in memory to respond to the form submit?  It seems like it will reload every submit.

Comment: Yes it is, but you'd need Redis or Memcache for that, PHP itself can't do that because it does not share memory in between requests everything gets destroyed after the request is served. But if you're going to be setting up Redis / Memchace I think it would be easier just to migrate to MySQL. For this kind of basic SQL query, you won't have any performance issues with plain MySQL / MariaDB.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on the size of the datatable you can save it on SESSION, use functions like shmop_open/shmop_write/shmop_read or (better yet) use some cache service like redis, but in one way or another the data will be stored and processed every time you pass by that place. I would tere the page in pieces, create one webservice to deal with the form post and another to show the form.

The easiest (not necessary safest or best way to do) would be ...
PS: I assume you are working with PDO and (obviously) the code bellow is an elaboration, it will not actually work

```
if (isset($_SESSION['db_datatable'])) {
    foreach ($_SESSION['db_datatable'] AS $item) {
        echo "<h1>".$item['some_row']."</h1>";
    }
} else {
    $filename = "../datafile.sqlite3";
    $db = new SQLite3($filename);
    $q = "SELECT distinct productId, title, price, name FROM datatable LIMIT 16";
    $results = $db->query($q);
    while ($row = $results->fetchArray()) {
        $_SESSION['db_datatable'][] = $row;
        echo "<h1>Results</h1>";
    }
    $db->close();
}
```

Hope I have been of some help. Cheers!